# Why can `BASH_SOURCE` be used to obtain the current directory of the executing script?

Tags: bash

I use `source` (`.`) in `$HOME/.bash_profile` to execute commands from a local `$HOME/.dotfiles/.bash_profile` file:

```
[[ -r "$HOME/.dotfiles/.bash_profile" ]] && . "$HOME/.dotfiles/.bash_profile"
```

Now, in `$HOME/.dotfiles/.bash_profile`, `$0` has the value of `"-bash"`, which means it cannot be used by `dirname` to retrieve the current directory of the executing script.

I've read that `BASH_SOURCE` should be populated with the name of the executing script (and it works!).

But **why** does `BASH_SOURCE` hold the name of the executing script, when it is defined in `man bash` as an array of source filenames corresponding to shell functions?

Futhermore, since `BASH_SOURCE` is defined to be an array, it's not safe to use it as follows to retrieve the current directory of the executing script, since it could hold multiple values: `dirname $BASH_SOURCE`?

`man bash`:

```
BASH_SOURCE
   An array variable whose members are the source filenames
   where the corresponding shell function names in the FUNCNAME array 
   variable are defined. The shell function ${FUNCNAME[$i]} is defined
   in the file ${BASH_SOURCE[$i]} and called from ${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}.
```

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why does `BASH_SOURCE` hold the name of the executing script, when it is defined in man bash as an array of source filenames corresponding to shell functions?

Why? Probably because it's useful to have the name of the file holding the main script available too.

Let's look at the description in the manual:

> `BASH_SOURCE`
> An array variable whose members are the source filenames where the corresponding shell function names in the `FUNCNAME` array variable are defined. The shell function `${FUNCNAME[$i]}` is defined in the file `${BASH_SOURCE[$i]}` and called from `${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}`

> `FUNCNAME`
> An array variable containing the names of all shell functions currently in the execution call stack. The element with index 0 is the name of any currently-executing shell function. The bottom-most element (the one with the highest index) is "main".

In function `foo`, called from the main script, `${FUNCNAME[0]}` contains `foo`, and `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` contains the name of the file that defined `foo`. `${FUNCNAME[1]}` contains `main` and `${BASH_SOURCE[1]}` contains the name of the main script file.

For `FUNCNAME`, it's explicitly stated that outside a function it's empty. For `BASH_SOURCE` it's different. The extension of always having the name of the main script file at the end of `BASH_SOURCE` is somewhat logical: function calls and returns only need to add/remove elements at the front.

It doesn't say that, but `BASH_SOURCE` also tracks sourced scripts (`. foo.sh` or such). They also don't show in `FUNCNAME` as long as no function is called, but do show up as `source` when there's an actual function in front.

> Futhermore, since `BASH_SOURCE` is defined to be an array, it's not safe to use it as follows to retrieve the current directory of the executing script, since it could hold multiple values: `dirname $BASH_SOURCE`?

I'm not sure if this is a question or a statement. But remember that referencing an array without an index is the same as using an index of `0`. So `$BASH_SOURCE` is `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`, and contains the name of the file that defined the current function. (Not that of the main script, for that you need something like `${BASH_SOURCE[ ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} - 1 ]}`.)

Note that the file name might still be something like `./foo.sh` or `foo.sh`, so `dirname` might not be able to tell anything useful.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful. What do you mean by “but do show up as source when there's an actual function in front.”?

Comment: How can `FUNCNAME` be empty if it always contains “main”?

Comment: “ function calls and returns only need to add/remove elements at the end.” - don’t you mean they add/remove at the front of `FUNCNAME`?

Comment: I don’t think that “ The extension of always having the name of the main script file at the end of BASH_SOURCE...” is explicitly stated in its definition?

Comment: @Shuzheng, (1) I mean that if there's a sourced script that called a function `foo`, then `FUNCNAME` will contain `foo`, `source`, and maybe `main`. If `foo.sh` contains `foo() { declare -p FUNCNAME; }; foo` then `bash -c '. foo.sh'` prints `declare -a FUNCNAME=([0]="foo" [1]="source")`. (It doesn't include `main` or anything for commands from `-c`, for some reason.)

Comment: @Shuzheng, (2) `FUNCNAME` doesn't always contain `main`, just if a function is being executed. Then it contains the function name, _and_ `main`. (Except if the main script is from `-c`, in which case it's missing...) That's probably so that you can just check `$FUNCNAME` and get blank when outside a function. On the other hand, `BASH_SOURCE` does contain values even outside a function. Confusing. (3) yes, add/remove at the front of course.

Comment: @Shuzheng, (4) it's not explicitly said as far as I can see, but it seems logical to have it there even when `FUNCNAME` is empty. Outside a function, `$FUNCNAME` doesn't make sense, but `$BASH_SOURCE` does. I don't want to go looking at the changelogs, but it does come to mind that perhaps the variables were just plain scalars at first, and then got extended to arrays, keeping the old behaviour.

Comment: Since it hasn't been mentioned: `BASH_SOURCE`, `FUNCNAME` and `BASH_LINENO` seem to have been added for debugging purposes: tell the line at which a function was invoked, in which file, and in which file it was declared. `BASH_SOURCE` + `BASH_LINENO` are useful even outside functions, they show the line at which a file has been sourced (and how sourced files are stacked). To me, too, it looks like this is not explicitly stated in the doc.